How to call and exit SQLcl from DOS command line for single use?
I'm using Oracle 21C and APEX 24.1   I'm converting a DOS backup script from oracle.apex.APEXExport to SQL.EXE (SQLcl).  I would like to call SQLcl for a single-use so  that it will return to the DOS script after the single function is executed.  In DOS, I used to use:
:; Export application 104 - The Library App.
java oracle.apex.APEXExport -db localhost:1521/xepdb1 -user %APEX_user% -password %db_password% -applicationid 104 
:; Prepend the exported file with %FileCore%
REN f104.sql %App104%

I understand how to log in to SQLcl.  I use:
C:\app\product\sqlcl\bin\sql jdbc:oracle:thin:SYSTEM/my_password@localhost/XEPDB1

Also, I understand how to backup a single application.  I use:
apex export -Applicationid 104

My question is how can I login in to SQLcl, execute the export function, and then exit SQLcl so that control is returned to DOS?
Thanks for looking at this.
ANSWER:
With someone else's help, I found the solution.  The "apex export" commands have to be placed in a sql file and then called from a DOS command file.  My code ended up as:
Backup.CMD:
C:\app\product\sqlcl\bin\sql jdbc:oracle:thin:%APEX_user%/%db_password%@localhost/XEPDB1 @C:\SS_Library_Backups\apex_backup.sql

apex_backup.sql
apex export -Applicationid 104
exit

I hope this helps someone with a similar question.

As you're capable of running Oracle 21C I guarantee you're not using Windows 9x or OS/2, therefore you're not using DOS, nor is it called the "DOS command-line". Please update your post to use the correct terminology for your platform.

I've googled for the current terminology, and there doesn't seem to be one clear answer.  I realize that there is no DOS in windows any more, yet most folks know what is meant by DOS command-line.  I honestly didn't recognize some of the other terms suggested in my search.
